# initialize object type constructor oracle

Tags: database, oracle

i'm developing a database in oracle.
I've created a supertype, answer, and a subtype, closed_answer. I've added a field "type" to distinguish them, but i want that this field is initialized in a constructor, in order to don't insert this field when i'm inserting a tuple in that table. i've tried, but when i insert a tuple in the table closed_answer, i have to specify the type, but i shouldn't. Where am i wrong?

```
create type answertyp as object(

id integer,

text varchar2(50),

type varchar2(25),

constructor function answertyp(self in out nocopy answertyp, text varchar2) return self as result) not final;

create type body answertyp is

constructor function answertyp(self in out nocopy answertyp, text varchar2) return self as result is

begin

self.text := text;

self.type:= 'answer';

return;

end;

end;
/

create type closed_answertyp under closed_answer(

constructor function closed_answertyp(self in out nocopy closed_answertyp, text varchar2) return self as result
) final;

create type body closed_answertyp is

constructor function closed_answertyp (self in out nocopy closed_answertyp, text varchar2) return self as result is

begin

self.text := text;

self.type := 'closed_answer';

return;

end;

end;
```

Now, if i try this query, it says that the number of argument is wrong. Any help? thanks

```
insert into answer select closed_answertyp(1, 'ten') from dual;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arguments in the SQL statement don't match the the arguments in the constructors.

Either add `id` to the constructor:

```
constructor function closed_answertyp (self in out nocopy closed_answertyp, id integer, text varchar2) return self as result is
```

Or remove the `id` from the SQL statement:

```
insert into answer select closed_answertyp('ten') from dual;
```